# Updating a summary table based on 2 other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Commisions (commisionID INT, EmployeeID, amount INT, created Datetime)

Sales (saleID INT, EmployeeID, amount INT, created datetime)
```

The summary table:

```
Employee (employeeID, totalCommisions INT, totalSales INT, created DateTime)
```

*There can be 0 or more rows per employee in both Commissions and Sales tables.*

Query#1 The query is to update the Employee table, summing the total commision into the totalCommision column for the employee, and the same for the totalSales.

Query#2 Same as above, but limit the total commission **for a given day** to $100.  So if they earned $150 commission in a day, set the value to $100.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the code you have written so far? People don't generally like to just write your code for you...

Comment: And how is it possible to determine which employee the commissions and sales belong to ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Employee 
SET    totalCommisions = Commisions.total,
       totalSales = Sales.total
FROM   ( SELECT employeeID, SUM(amount) AS total
         FROM Commisions
         GROUP BY employeeID ) AS Commisions,
       ( SELECT employeeID, SUM(amount) AS total
         FROM Sales
         GROUP BY employeeID ) AS Sales
WHERE  Employee.employeeID = Commisions.employeeID
AND    Employee.employeeID = Sales.employeeID
```

The second query you should try on your own.